# Facebook developer settings unable to verify package

Tags: android, facebook

In Facebook Settings, even though I check my package name on Google play is correct and my app has already published on GG play, Facebook still show this message 
"We were unable to verify your package name <> on Google Play. Please double-check your package name before proceeding.
If your app is not publicly listed on Google Play yet, you may safely ignore this warning."
What is wrong with this?

Comment: com.company.productname, for example

Comment: yes, for example, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.company.productname . Because my app has been published.

Comment: Can you provide your App ID -and- the correct package name as you've used in the Google Play store?

Comment: it suddenly works today, no warning from facebook developer team. Is that because my app just upload a few days on play store and FB cannot recognize it. If it is so, it is totally weird.

Comment: That indeed sounds strange. It should not have a cache. If you can paste here your FB app ID and you google store link I might find out more for you. But it's working now, at least :)

Comment: so, we need to upload apps to the play store if facebook login was work ?

Answer (score 1):

for me the "Bundle Version Code" was less than the last version, so I changed for a new one and it worked